# HTTP over Multicast UDP (SSDP)

Tags: netty

I am building a UPnP server on netty (ala [Holmes](http://ccheneau.github.io/Holmes/) but pure netty for all protocol stacks - addressing, discovery, description, control, eventing, presentation and out of band streaming - no cling framework etc).

I have the UDP multicast bootstrap working but it doesn’t look elegant (i've done some kludging to work out viable interfaces etc).

I can't quite figure out (without a lot more tracing) how netty uses specific interfaces? I think this is how it works:

- if just use port number in bootstrap e.g. .localAddress(1900) then will bind to and listen on wlldcard/all interfaces (0.0.0.0) and the kernel will figure out what to do.
- if specify InetAddress/SocketAddress then will bind to this single one e.g. .localAddress(“127.0.0.1”, 1900)
- if try and specify multiples e.g. 
  .localAddress(“127.0.0.1”, 1900) 
  .localAddress(“10.1.1.2”, 1900)
  (the logging handler shows binding to just the last one specified)

Can I specify more than one interface or is it just one or all?

Does anyone know of a simple util that can smartly work out viable interfaces (the standard JDK NetworkInterfaces one doesn't play nice when have virtual interfaces etc when have a hypervisor installed - and they don't show up as virtual)?

For multicast need to join to a group to send to multicast address:
channel.joinGroup("239.255.255.250", NetworkInterface.getByName("en0")).syncUninterruptibly();
Looks like can only bind to one interface - not sure yet how this will impact when send from one interface but receive back on another and vice versa (the upnp spec looks particular about this - "A multi-homed device MUST perform the SSDP announcement procedures on each of its UPnP-enabled interfaces.").

It runs if join more than once:
channel.joinGroup("239.255.255.250", NetworkInterface.getByName("en0")).syncUninterruptibly();
channel.joinGroup("239.255.255.250", NetworkInterface.getByName("en1")).syncUninterruptibly();

If try and use joinGroup(InetAddress multicastAddress) it compiles but I get a runtime error.

What's the best/easiest way to get the same interfaces from the bootstrap set up for the multicast as well?